# log parameters values of the procedure called by Hibernate in the web application logs hosted in tomcat server

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, stored-procedures, plsql

I encountered an error when calling a stored procedure in an oracle database by Hibernate.
I use a web application based on spring 4 and Hibernate 5.
I would like to log the parameters values of the called procedure in a local tomcat server where I deployed the application.

I use `Slf4j/Logback` for logging.

I configured Hibernate to log all the executed sql queries with values of its outbound parameters using this code :

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"/>
```

And this is ok.

Now I would like to log the parameters values of the procedure called by Hibernate.

I tried this configuration:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.procedure." level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.procedure.internal" level="TRACE"/>
<logger name="oracle.jdbc.driver" level="DEBUG"/>
```

But it didn't work.

I figure out that we can't log the procedure paramters called in this post:
 [can't log parameters values of procedure in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821275/stored-procedure-parameter-values-logging)

but he doesn't mention that he was using Hibernate.

So I would like to know if there is a way to log the procedures parametes values with Hiberante?

And if it is not the case, I am just curious, why we can log the parameters values of the sql queries executed by Hibernate and not that of procedures?

Thanks in advance.